# What does the word "Rep." mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology

[image]

What's meaning of the 'Rep.'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Representative**, in the U.S. political sense: that is, someone elected to the [House of Representatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_of_Representatives).  Specifically, [this guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Lee_(politician)).  Not [this more famous guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Lee):

[image]

**Edit:** As Justin points out in comments, that’s what *Rep.* means in this particular example, but in other contexts it can mean [many other things too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep).

Comment: Note for non-English speakers: this is the meaning of "Rep." as used in the OP's example.  "Rep" can mean other things in different contexts, for example, as shorthand for "reputation".

Comment: @Justin Morgan: I would say that "non-English speakers" is the wrong group - "non-Americans" would be better.  It is a title, like `Mr, Dr, Lord, Sir`, just one specific to a certain role in American politics.

Comment: Fair enough.  But is `Representative` as an elected official unique to the US?

Comment: @Justing Morgan: For reference, the matching role in UK politics is a Member of Parliament, they are usually styled with the suffix `MP`, and if they are privy councillors, then the title `Rt. Hon.` in formal writing.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: It is not unique to the US as a term for an elected official, but is not used in all English speaking countries.  Most English speaking countries call their members MPs, even though the lower house in those countries is often called the "House of Representatives" (as opposed to the "House of Commons" in the UK).

Comment: @Justin Morgan: many other countries (eg Australia) have elected politicians called ‘representatives’; but I don’t know if there are any others where *Rep.* gets used as a title like in the US (in Australia, iirc, it isn’t typically used that way).

Comment: @PLL: In Australia I *believe* they use `MP` still, even though they do call their legislators *representatives*.

Comment: In the UK, at least, 'rep' is short for 'repetition' when it refers to the number of times a fitness exercise is to be performed.

Comment: "Representative" may also refer to a member of a state legislature.

Answer (score 5):

It should be pointed out that this is actually ambiguous in this case. It could well stand for *Representative*, as the gentleman in question was in fact a member of the US House of Representatives at the time.

However, it is also a common abbreviation for *Republican*, which is the political party he is a member of.

I'd guess the poster was aware of this ambiguity, and was fine with it. Space is so limited in a tweet that doing double-duty with a word like this is often considered a good thing.

Comment: I've never seen it used that way and I believe that standard styling would be: *Rep. Christopher Lee (R-NY)*.  But I'm not an American so perhaps I haven't seen that alternative meaning.

Comment: @z7sgѪ - There's a lot of truth in that. The standard on TV at least is to put an *R* or *D* in parenthesis after the person's name, occasionally eloaborated with the district or state they represent. However, on TV most folks are pretending at being non-partisan. Online often the poster's point is to emphasise the party rather than the person (as that is who they really want to damage or build up).